# Combine two rows of cell which includes same element

Tags: arrays, matlab, row, cell

For example I have a cell array like:

Column1----Column2

'aaaa'--------4

'bbbb'--------5

'cccc'---------2

'cccc'---------0

'dddd'--------0

'dddd'--------3

'eeee'--------0

'ffff'-----------0

And what I want is to merge the rows which has same elements. Finally what I want to obtain is:

'aaaa'--------4

'bbbb'--------5

'cccc'---------2

'dddd'--------3

'eeee'--------0

'ffff'-----------0

I'm looking for an answer without for loops.

Comment: Anything you have tried? Code, other answers? What difficulties have you encountered?

Comment: Best answer is :[A,B] = unique(arr(:,1),'first'); arr = arr(B,:); but this doesn't solve my problem totally for the cases like 'dddd'--------0(repeated row is first) 'dddd'--------3.It'll give me:'dddd'--------0 but I want to obtain :'dddd'--------3

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`arr([arr{:,2}] ~= 0,:)`

arr -
rows: all rows of arr such that the second column does not equal 0,
columns: all columns

Might be a syntax error in there somewhere, been a while since I used Matlab...

Edit: New answer

```
non_zero = transpose([arr{:,2}] ~= 0);
arr = arr(non_zero | ~ismember(arr(:,1),arr(non_zero,1)),:)
```

Essentially what I'm doing: Get all rows such that the right hand side is not zero, OR the left-hand side is not a member of the left-hand sides of the non-zero rows. The latter condition will only be satisfied for rows with zero with no matching left-hand side in the non-zero rows (and hence not repeats). Now keep in mind that this will still not work if you have any duplicate rows (same left and right-hand side). If that's a possibility then do this:

```
non_zero = transpose([arr{:,2}] ~= 0);
arr = arr(non_zero | ~ismember(arr(:,1),arr(non_zero,1)),:);
[~,U] = unique(arr(:,1));
arr = arr(U,:)
```

Comment: You need to convert the second column into a matrix to make it work: `arr([arr{:,2}] ~= 0, :)`

Comment: I've edited my question. I shouldn't delete all rows which has 0 value, just repeated ones.

Comment: Okay, try this:

`[A,B] = unique(arr(:,1),'first');
arr = arr(B,:);`

Comment: but what if the case is:
'dddd'--------0(repeated row is first)

'dddd'--------3

then it'll give me:'dddd'--------0
but I want to obtain :'dddd'--------3

Answer (score 0):

Find all completely unique strings (i.e ffff_**0 and ffff__***1 are unique, but aaaa*_1 and aaaa___1 are obviously not unique. (apparently underscores represent formatting?)

Once you have that, do the same thing with just the letters.

I am pretty sure you will have to do that (above) in some capacity to get your desired output, and if that's the case, I think you are right on the edge of the speed tradeoff between for loops and all that extra memory allocation and sorting through values finding unique ones.

Comment: ___ 's are for seperate columns. There is nothing about _. Column1 contains strings which are same or different and column 2 is just double values.